# How to change MPM prefork to worker on default Apache OSX installation?

Tags: apache, php

On CentOS, the Apache configuration can be found in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

How to change MPM prefork to worker on default Apache OSX installation?

Comment: although answeredm flagged as off topic as should probably be over on the think different/apple site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think its that easy with default apache, not without the risk of it reverting on a software update, the config files would be in /etc/apache2 though

its probably simpler and more reliable to install something like macports and install apache2 from there, that way it will be persistent of apple software updates and much more flexible in configuration

Comment: are you sure that Apple Software Update would sweep all the default Apache settings? that's pretty scary.. if that's so, I would definitely use macports or brew installations

Comment: I'm just thinking that if I use those homebrew or macports, why would I buy Mac Mini Server (using Lion OSX server)?

Comment: lion server just gives a nice gui on the server stuff, and i think its as powerful for apache as it used to be on snow leopard, cant confirm config change resets of apache but i know that everytime i messed with default php previously without installing from macports it would get reset on the next point upgrade

Comment: all the config files are gone or renamed as for example, http.conf.something_previous_version?